# Rome 0.9 does not work correctly when module classloader order : parent last

Tags: log4j, websphere, classloader, websphere-7

Project description:
WebSphere Application Server 7.Maven project which uses Rome0.9.

```html
<dependency>
    <groupId>rome</groupId>
    <artifactId>rome</artifactId>
    <version>0.9</version>
</dependency>
```

I was solving the problem with log4j not logging. The problem was that log4j.properties were already set in parent project.
That's why I changed module's classloader order to Parent Last.
It fixed the problem with log4j, but application now throws following exception:

```
ParsingFeedException: Invalid XML
```

I've checked parent loaded libraries and they include the same version of Rome - 0.9.

It seems that I'm missing some dependencies in my project. I wonder if there is some way to find out which libraries are missing?

Maybe you could suggest any other solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't have a solution for searching missing loaded library. 
However this workaround worked for me:
I reconfigured log4j in static block of main servlet class.

```
static Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(FeedAggregatorServlet.class);
static {
     Properties p = new Properties();
     ClassLoader classLoader = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader();
     try {
         p.load(classLoader.getResourceAsStream("/FeedAggregatorlog4j.properties"));
     } catch (IOException e) {
         e.printStackTrace();             
     }
    PropertyConfigurator.configure(p);
}
```